# What does ::* (asterisk after scope op) means in C++ template?

Tags: c++

Please help me understand a code snippet from Facebook Pop: [PopVector.h](https://github.com/facebook/pop/blob/master/pop/POPVector.h)

The template class `Vector2` contains a static member `_v` which looks like to be the backing data of an instance of `Vector2`:

```
private:
    typedef T Vector2<T>::* const _data[2];
    static const _data _v;
```

`_v` is instantiated by the following line:

```
template<typename T>
  const typename Vector2<T>::_data Vector2<T>::_v = { &Vector2<T>::x, &Vector2<T>::y };
```

then `_v` is used to implement index operators:

```
const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return this->*_v[i]; }
T& operator[](size_t i) { return this->*_v[i]; }
```

I'm not familiar with this code pattern and have several questions about it:

1. What does the typedef line mean? I don't understand `Vector2<T>::*`
2. Why `_v` has to be a static member? It seems it's not shared across instances, which doesn't follow static semantic in C++ AFAICT.

Comment: It's a pointer-to-member.

Comment: The idea behind this pattern is to allow `x` and `y` to be named, but also to allow access by index. `_v` holds two pointers, which give a way to access the `x` and `y` elements of an arbitrary `Vector2`. pointers-to-members have nothing to do with templates, and can just as easily be used in non-templates.

Comment: @Mankarse That may be the motivation, but there are more effective means of doing this (especially when there are only two members).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether in a template or elsewhere, `::*` is a C++ token, only
usable in a type expression, in the context
*class_name*::*.  It declares a pointer to member.

In your case, the typedef says that `_data` is an alias for
a const pointer to a member of `Vector2<T>` which has type
`T const[2]`.

EDIT:

I got the actual definition wrong: `_data` is an alias for an array[2] of const pointers to members of `Vector2<T>` of type `T`.  This is obvious in the instantiation, where the object is initialized with two pointers to members.

Comment: @T.C I noticed when I looked at the initialization.  Pointers to members often result in very awkward and hard to read declarations (and should usually be avoided, because of this).

Comment: @JamesKanze may I ask why `_v` has to be static?

Comment: @CuperHector Because the author wanted it static.  In this case, he wants one single instance, independent of the number of instances of his class.  (Practically speaking, if it weren't static, he could use plain pointers, rather than pointers to members, because when he initialized it, he would have an instance of the class.  But if it weren't static, it would increase the size of each instance.)

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for helping me get the full picture.